# My list of terms of custom taxonomy displays 7 times

Tags: customization, taxonomy

I'm building a custom page template to show a list of terms from a custom taxonomy named "autore", and I don't know why it displays the full list more than one time (seven times, to be precise). Can anyone help?

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Archive Custom Taxonomy
 */

get_header(); the_post(); ?>

<?php
$args=array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false
);
$output = 'names'; // or objects
$operator = 'and';
$taxonomies=get_taxonomies($args,$output,$operator);
if  ($taxonomies) {
    foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {
        $terms = get_terms([
            'taxonomy' => 'autore',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'order' => 'ASC',
        ]);
        foreach ( $terms as $term) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php get_footer();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any chance you have 7 terms in the list?  It looks like your foreach is recursive and you output the list once for each term.

Comment: I edited the post: as you can see there are 18 elements in the taxonomy, but in the preview when the list ends it's repeated. This happens 7 times.